# Use a plot from R in C#

Tags: c#, r, plot

I need your help...to solve my problem...

I want to use the `plot()` function from `R` in `C#`. However, I don't know how to put the plot that I get from R, into *picture box* or *panel* in C#.

Here the code that I've used to get plot from R:

```
engine.Evaluate("r.plot <- plot(r$condition, r$access, 
                                main='condition category vs access category',
                                xlab='condition', ylab='access', 
                                pch=1, col='blue')" );
```

How could I put the plot into *picture box* or *panel* in C# ???

Answer (score 5):

The best working option is to save a file from R and open with a picture box. A couple of contributors to R.NET wrote code currently in an alpha NuGet package [R.NET.Graphics](http://www.nuget.org/packages/R.NET.Community.Graphics/). This was a *prototype* for a seamless graphic device for R. A fully fledged device would be a lot of work, and this graphics module is not actively developed currently (anyone game for it out there?).

Have a look at [RDotNet.Graphics.Tests](https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet/tree/master/RDotNet.Graphics.Tests) there is code showing side by side the visual output via R.NET.Graphics and from a loaded file.

Comment: It appears R now is integrated into SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) 2016 https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4127/sql-server-2016-r-services-display-r-plots-in-reporting-services/ and there is VisualStudio integration as well https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/03/22/introducing-r-tools-for-visual-studio-3/